# How is it possible that redirect works, even after applied rule in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a wordpress site with an htaccess that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

And then after I have the following redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /plans /samples
```

And this is doing the redirect correctly.

How is that even possible? If it is declared after the conditions that say that if the file or directory does not exist, let's index.php handle the request? It shouldn't even get to that redirect, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `Rewrite****` directives all belong to the mod_rewrite module, while the `Redirect` directive belongs to the mod_alias module. Both modules are in the URL mapping processing pipeline so both sets of directives get applied.

If you want the redirect to work in-line with the rewrite rules, then you shouldn't use mod_alias, use only mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteRule ^plans(.*)$ /samples$1 [L,R=301]
```

is the mod_rewrite equivalent of your `Redirect`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am still wondering that if the first rule (Rewrite) it's applied, then the URL gets rewritten to index.php, how can the Redirect rule then work? If the URL itself has changed?

Comment: @HommerSmith mod_alias gets applied first, the URI is changed and marked for an external redirect, then mod_rewrite gets applied, and the `/samples` gets rewritten to `/index.php`, then the redirect happens (because the request has been marked to redirect).